# Luatexja conflicts with KOMA script

Tags: luatex, koma-script, vim-latex, luatexja

After running into a bit of a wall with certain things in XeTeX I decided to start experimenting a bit with LuaTeX. Unfortunately I ran into a problem I couldn't solve pretty much instantly.

I really need CJK support. According to some quick research, the way to do this in LuaTex is using the `luatexja` package. However this package throws the following rather annoying warning whenever I use it with a KOMA script document class (which I have so far been using extensively):

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \selectfont   has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.
```

The reason it is annoying is that it causes vim's `latex-suite` to close the file I'm working on and opening `lltjfont.sty` (which according to its path appears to be a patch for `luatexja`) for inspection.

The error is thrown on the mere inclusion of the package, regardless of whether or not I actually do something with it. For an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% luatexja-fontenc also includes fontenc for use in
% conjunction. However the warning is thrown with just
% luatexja as well, so fontenc doesn't seem to be the
% problem
\usepackage{luatexja-fontenc}
\begin{document}
Dummy text
\end{document}
```

Do you guys know a way how I can resolve the conflict (or at least silence the warning since the document does compile fine)?

Btw, I'm on TexLive2018. My `\listfiles` output:

```
scrreprt.cls    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basi
cs and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent ba
sics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (type area)
fontspec.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2018-08-23 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018-08-23 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-08-23 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2018-08-23 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
fontspec-luatex.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
luatexja-fontspec.sty    2018/07/31 fontspec support of LuaTeX-ja
l3keys2e.sty    2018-08-23 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
luatexja.sty    2018/08/25 Japanese Typesetting with Lua(La)TeX
luatexja-core.sty    2017/11/12 Core of LuaTeX-ja
luatexbase.sty    2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
ctablestack.sty    2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
everyhook.sty    2014/11/26 v1.2 (SVN Rev: 12)\ Hooks for low level TeX everyX p
rimitives.
svn-prov.sty    2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
ltj-base.sty    2017/05/05
ltj-latex.sty    2018/08/24 LaTeX support of LuaTeX-ja
lltjfont.sty    2018/01/12 Patch to NFSS2 for LuaTeX-ja
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
lltjdefs.sty    2018/06/15 Default font settings of LuaTeX-ja
lltjcore.sty    2018/06/15 Patch to LaTeX2e Kernel for LuaTeX-ja
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
filehook-scrlfile.sty    2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for scrlfile package
lltjp-geometry.sty    2018/01/19 Patch to geometry for LuaTeX-ja with vertical w
riting mode
luatexja-compat.sty    2018/03/29 Compatibility with pTeX
luatexja-fontspec-26h.sty    2018/08/02 fontspec support of LuaTeX-ja
```

Comment: Do you have any real font issues? The warning you cite is just that, a warning. Hence, could you test whether there are actually problems?

Comment: That's only a information not a conflict. everysel tests against the original selectfont definition, but scrartcl has added already patch. If your editor is not able to cope with such warnings, change the editor.

Comment: Yes, I know it’s just a warning, and I wouldn’t care much if it didn’t force-switch me to that .sty file after compilation. I tried to block the warning or at least stop it from automatically switching files, but without success. `vim-latex` does let you do that normally but it didn’t want to work – apparently the options for that are applied only when using the normal compilation command, not with a makefile (which I used to try out LuaTeX without having to change my global compilation rule). I’ll have a bit more of a look into it. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using vim, you can customise its reactions in case of warnings and errors. See here -- http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/compiler-output-customization.html -- for the way to adapt, but however, the whole section about compiling LaTeX seems worth reading: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-compiling.html

The point is: you'll get every time you compile a bunch of warnings, so it really might be worth the time and effort to customise vim.

Comment: Thank you. I know it’s just a warning and I wouldn’t really care much if it didn’t open that .sty file for inspection after every compilation. I had in fact tried blocking the warning and it didn’t work. It seems that for some reasons the warning filters seem to only be applied when using the default <leader>ll compilation command but _not_ when using a makefile (which I had done in order to test LuaTeX without having to change my global compile rule). I’ll have a bit more of a look into whether or not there is some way around that. Anyways, thanks you very much for the reminder!